# tokenize a char* for a shell program

Tags: c, char, tokenize

I'm making a shell program that supports both user arguments and io redirection. I am having trouble with io redirection, eg:

```
$cat < hello > world
```

first I save the arguments in a `char*` array. I check if the first char is `<` or `>` and if it is I need to shave off the first character and make a file descriptor.

Here's what I'm doing.

```
    char* args[50];//<-- cat <hello and >world are in here
    char* fd[2];
    int fdin, fdout;
    if(args[j][0] == '<'){
        close(fdout);
        strncpy(fd[0], args[j][1]. strlen(args[j])-1);
        fdin = open(fd[0], O_RDONLY);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To ease your work, begin drafting what your input looks like in some formal language, for example:

```
line : ID+ ( '<' ID | '>' '>'? ID )* ( '|' line )* '\0'
```

Where ID is run of chars where each either `isAlpha` or `isDigit` or `isSpecial` separated by other chars (like spaces, tabs, '>', '<', '|' and so on.

During the parsing it will be easier to add the first part (`ID+`) in a linked list and later translate that list to argv-argc pair.

The rest are treated specially (not in the linked list because they are not as general):

- IO redirection with '<' and '>' and '>>'; then
- pipelining with '|'.

Since the language is recursive (note the `( '|' line )*`) your parser lends itself easily also to a recursive function (see? you have a function `parse` and when it reaches '|' it calls itself to parse the rest).

NB: although I expressed the line syntax in something like BNF notation doesn't mean that you should use a language parsing lib or compiler (yacc comes to mind). This language is just too simple and easy to implement to worth all the headache that come with these tools.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have never worked with the `argc` and `argv` parameters of `main()` before? You don't need to create your own array, C already does that for you.  You end up with this `argv` array:

```
argv[0] = "cat"
argv[1] = "<"
argv[2] = "hello"
argv[3] = ">"
argv[4] = "world"
```

Or:

```
argv[0] = "cat"
argv[1] = "<hello"
argv[2] = ">world"
```

Or any combination of that, depending on the whitespace used on the command line parameters.

Then you can do something like this (error handling omitted from brevity):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char* fd[2];
    int fdin = -1, fdout = -1;

    fd[0] = fd[1] = NULL;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        if (argv[i][0] == '<')
        {
            if (argv[i][1] != '\0')
                fd[0] = &(argv[i][1]);
            else
                fd[0] = argv[i+1];

            fdin = open(fd[0], O_RDONLY);
        }

        else if (argv[i][0] == '>')
        {
            if (argv[i][1] != '\0')
                fd[1] = &(argv[i][1]);
            else
                fd[1] = argv[i+1];

            fdout = open(fd[1], O_WRONLY);
        }
    }

    ...

    if (fdin != -1)
        ... read from fdin as needed ...
    else
        ... read from stdin as needed ...

    ...

    if (fdout != -1)
        ... write to fdout as needed ...
    else
        ... write to stdout as needed ...

    ...

    if (fdin != -1)
       close(fdin);

    if (fdout != -1)
        close(fdout);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this does not answer OP question. He wants to implement the shell himself (not a shell that does the all the parsing job ). So he has something to read input (to char buffer) and parse this line.

Comment: Note: `argv[argc] == NULL`. §5.1.2.2.1 2

Comment: I do know how to use argc and argv but this is a shell program as in I execute it first with ./a.out and then I am prompted for some command eg. ls -l. But I have already found a better way of approaching this problem thanks for the help :D